# Detect which usb device is sending data

Tags: c#, usb, drivers

I have 3 usb devices (barcode scanner, same model) I want to do an application that receive the input of the barcode scanner.

The problem is that I want to know which scanner has scan the barcode.

Is there a way to do this ?

I found this information, but they don't tell if the same device will have the same ID 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553356.aspx

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finaly found something :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx

This was my solution, thanks all who have take a look at my problem.